Jump to Next row in excel after reaching to a specific column

My excel sheet looks like this. BOX A and BOX B are barcode scanned data. I have changed the move direction to 'right' in advanced setting so that it automatically moves to Box B after Box A.
Now after generating the result in Column C I want my cursor automatically directed on the next row on Column A.
Please let me know if this is possible.

I'm afraid this isn't possible with formulas, this is probably more of a VBA thing. However, what you could do with formulas, is just insert your data in a straight row, or column, and then use the WRAP() function on a different sheet/below.

Use a table "Insert > table" - then a new line is added automatically

You can achieve this with VBA using the so-called Worksheet Change event. If that's an option, you must save the file as a macro-enabled file (.xlsm or .xlsb) though. Let us know by adding the vba tag at the bottom of your post.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This formula create a continuous table while filling in data in example row 26. Extend the range A26:DF26 to the desired size.
=LET(dat,TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(WRAPROWS(A26:DF26,2),1),1), data,TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(WRAPROWS(A26:DF26,2),2),1), HSTACK(dat,data,TOCOL(IF(dat=data,"MATCH","NO MATCH"),2)))

